# HttpErrorResponse when requested from Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular for my frontend and golang/postgresql for backend.
I'm sending the same exact json payload from postman and angular. 
It's working on postman but angular is returning this error:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error",...}
```

I tried removing headers and adding them and nothing changed.
My code:

In the edit page :

```
   let json = JSON.stringify(session)
        console.log(json)
        this.httpService.updateSession(json).subscribe()
```

In the httpService:(please check the comment here)

```
 private headers: HttpHeaders;
  private accessPointUrl: string = "http://localhost:3001";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
  }

  public updateSession(payload) {
    console.log(payload) //I'm taking this payload from console, add it to postman, and everything works 
    return this.http.put(this.accessPointUrl+ '/updateSession', payload,{headers: this.headers}); //I tried removing the headers and playing with it
  }
}
```

when sending from angular the error in the backend appears as: `pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""`

I'm stuck and I really can't figure out the problem. Please help and thank you.

Comment: isnt that self explainatory? empty string is not a valid timestamp. Probably its missing in payload

Comment: No I'm sending it full, no empty strings

Comment: Its not what your backend says.\

Comment: I'm sending the exact same json I wrote in the console on the postman and update is successful

Comment: *I'm sending the exact same json I wrote in the console* The fact that you print something in the console does not mean you are sending it. Check network tab - console is a missleading tool. Besides - don't you think it is bizarre that sending the same thing via browser and postman generates such diffeerent results? It should give you some thoughts about that.

Comment: You are not the first and unfortunetly not the last persons that make similar claims based on false assumptions or lack of knowledge. Feel free to include postman payload and browser (network tab) payload so you will se the exact differences (but there are any right?)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from `pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""` you sending the wrong data type to `postgresql` Database. So, first of all, check data types which you send, before input them into the DB